# How to get all values from python enum class?

Tags: python, enums

I'm using Enum4 library to create an enum class as follows:

```
class Color(Enum):
    RED = 1
    BLUE = 2
```

I want to print `[1, 2]` as a list somewhere. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can use [IntEnum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#intenum):

```
from enum import IntEnum

class Color(IntEnum):
   RED = 1
   BLUE = 2


print(int(Color.RED))   # prints 1
```

To get list of the ints:

```
enum_list = list(map(int, Color))
print(enum_list) # prints [1, 2]
```

Comment: You use third party one. But it also says it has intenum

Comment: How do i print like 
[(1,'RED'), (2, 'BLUE')]

Comment: What about this: `a = [(int(v), str(v)) for v in Color]` and then `print(a)`.

Comment: How about this: `[(color.value, color.name) for color in Color]`

Comment: @vlad-ardelean's comment is the best and most pythonic. That's idiomatic usage of the Enum type, elegant, and eminently readable

Comment: this does not work for str enums: ```>>> class QuantityUnit(str, Enum):
...     bushels = 'bushels'
...     pounds = 'pounds'
...     tons = 'tons'
...     kilograms = 'kilograms'
...     metric_tons = 'metric_tons'
...     cwt = 'hundredweight'
>>> list(map(str, QuantityUnit))
['QuantityUnit.bushels', 'QuantityUnit.pounds', 'QuantityUnit.tons', 'QuantityUnit.kilograms', 'QuantityUnit.metric_tons', 'QuantityUnit.cwt']
```

Comment: `[enum_color.value for enum_color in Color]` would achieve exactly that in a pythonic way.

Comment: A better way is just `class Color(int,Enum): ...`. With that, you can do `sorted(Color)` (sort by value) and `Color.RED>2` (treat as number). Additionally... `np.array(Color) (int64 array), np.array(Color, dtype=object), list(Color)`

Answer (score 947):

You can do the following:

```
[e.value for e in Color]
```

Comment: Suprisingly complicated for python to check if a value is in the enum, `if foo in [e.value for e in Color]`

Comment: @run_the_race This isn't pretty but it's shorter: `if foo in e.__members__.values()`

Comment: @ori your example does not make sense because it will fail if `1` is not in `Color`. Going this way you could do `try: Color(1) except ValueError: ...` which is actually very pythonic

Comment: @PaulBissex your example does not work. `e.__members__.values()` returns instances of the enum objects, not their values.

Comment: No need to iterate, follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60763091/2582581

Comment: more pythonic: `map(attrgetter('value'), Color)`

Comment: @amohr I think both are pretty pythonic in terms of syntax etc. while yours requires to import `operator` library explicitly.

Answer (score 155):

Based on the answer by @Jeff, refactored to use a `classmethod` so that you can reuse the same code for any of your enums:

```
from enum import Enum

class ExtendedEnum(Enum):

    @classmethod
    def list(cls):
        return list(map(lambda c: c.value, cls))

class OperationType(ExtendedEnum):
    CREATE = 'CREATE'
    STATUS = 'STATUS'
    EXPAND = 'EXPAND'
    DELETE = 'DELETE'

print(OperationType.list())
```

Produces:

```
['CREATE', 'STATUS', 'EXPAND', 'DELETE']
```

Comment: Beautiful! I've been trying to do exactly this for about an hour but was use not grasping the need for the classmethod. I was attempting to just subclass and add a property attribute, but could not get the super().__init__() to properly pass arguments to Enum. Thanks!

Comment: Why make things extra confusing with a map? Guido wanted to remove them because you can do the same thing with generators more clearly. `[c.value for c in cls]` is the preferred syntax in Python. (Doesn't matter here but one benefit is avoiding the extra per-item lambda calls and the map overhead). Or just the builtin `Enum._member_names_`.

Comment: I think you could rename the `list method to `values` in case other functions are added that return lists. And Q. would changing `@classmethod` to `@staticmethod` be cleaner and closer to the intent?

Comment: @Carl 1) Yes, `Enum.values` is better. 2) No, `@classmethod` is needed to iterate over the members.

Comment: This is a clever solution, but not, I think, a good one. It only works for enums that you own and control.

Comment: Using list comprehension like this: `[e.value for e in Color]` would be better than list of map of lambda

Comment: Only works for unique values

Comment: this replicates the "_member_names" attribute does. See solution below

Answer (score 120):

Use `_member_names_` for a quick easy result if it is just the names, i.e.

```
Color._member_names_
```

Also, you have `_member_map_` which returns an ordered dictionary of the elements. This function returns a `collections.OrderedDict`, so you have `Color._member_map_.items()` and `Color._member_map_.values()` to play with. E.g.

```
return list(map(lambda x: x.value, Color._member_map_.values()))
```

will return all the valid values of Color

Comment: Underrated answer.

Comment: This is the real answer without any additional jargon or third part Enum. Works out of box.

Comment: This seems a little dirty though, because it's using the private properties of Enum class.

Comment: @HosseyNJF `_member_names_` is not private, it is just a magic/dunder method.

Comment: @EliuX, why did you revert my edit? It seems like you changed it back yourself anyway...

Comment: Sorry, I reverted it by mistake and then I reapplied the change. Sorry about that.

Comment: @EliuX Doesn't the leading underscore indicate a non-public value per PEP 8? It's also [not documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html).

Comment: @Antrikshy dunders are a way of Python to avoid conflicts with functions/variables defined by the user, specially with possible Python updates. They are not meant to be public, so they should compete for your attention in your IDE with those who really are public, but they are there to be used in cases like this.

Comment: Sure. I’d just be slightly concerned about having to worry about it when upgrading Python. Since it isn’t documented, there’s a possibility it could be missing in the changelog and migration notes. As long as you have good tests… ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: About the notation of `_member_names_`, the factory function [collections.namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) is a quintessential example of look-like-private-but-are-production-safe underscored attributes/methods (e.g. `_asdict` etc.) in order to avoid confusion with the user defined attributes —I always trip on `pandas.DataFrame.name`, `pandas.DataFrame.rank` etc. were this does not happen...

Comment: @brandonscript overrated answer. I don't think it's a good idea to rely on _private_ methods or fields. The custom base-enum is much cleaner and safer.

Comment: @t3chb0t Python's decision to make it a `_` (private, but not private internal) was a choice to say "don't use this unless you know what you're doing". If they didn't want us using private methods, they should have made them `__` or maybe Python should have actual method privacy 

Comment: It's also incorrect. In my case it returns "MYVALUE" instead of "MyValue"

Answer (score 45):

To use Enum with any type of value, try this:
Updated with some improvements... Thanks @Jeff, by your tip!

```
from enum import Enum

class Color(Enum):
    RED = 1
    GREEN = 'GREEN'
    BLUE = ('blue', '#0000ff')

    @staticmethod
    def list():
        return list(map(lambda c: c.value, Color))

print(Color.list())
```

As result:

```
[1, 'GREEN', ('blue', '#0000ff')]
```

Comment: I would use  @classmethod instead of @ staticmethod

Comment: @ISONecroMAn I guess `@classmethod` would require to create instance of `Color` class. That's why `staticmethod` seems to be correct choice here.

Comment: @LeonidDashko not at all. See my answer.

Comment: @LeonidDashko @dangoonfast is correct.  You can use `@classmethod` and use `return list(map(lambda c: c.value, cls))` instead.

Comment: Trying to improve the speed of this, there are two notes: using `Color.__members__.values()` instead of Color in the `map()` call will give you a 30% boost right away. You can then get a bit more speed by replacing the lambda with `operator.attrgetter('value')`.

Comment: If you have so many Enum Values that speed matters more than readability here, there is something else wrong...

Answer (score 34):

Just use:

```
[e.value for e in Color]
```

Produces:

> [1, 2]

And to get the names, use:

```
[e.name for e in Color]
```

Produces:

> ['RED', 'BLUE']

Answer (score 25):

class `enum.Enum` is a class that solves all your enumeration needs, so you just need to inherit from it, and add your own fields. Then from then on, all you need to do is to just call it's attributes: `name` & `value`:

```
from enum import Enum

class Letter(Enum):
   A = 1
   B = 2
   C = 3

print({i.name: i.value for i in Letter})
# prints {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}
```

Answer (score 18):

You can have a `SuperEnum` like:

```py
from enum import Enum

class SuperEnum(Enum):    
    @classmethod
    def to_dict(cls):
        """Returns a dictionary representation of the enum."""
        return {e.name: e.value for e in cls}
    
    @classmethod
    def keys(cls):
        """Returns a list of all the enum keys."""
        return cls._member_names_
    
    @classmethod
    def values(cls):
        """Returns a list of all the enum values."""
        return list(cls._value2member_map_.keys())
```

and use it like:

```py
class Roles(SuperEnum):
    ADMIN = 1
    USER = 2
    GUEST = 3
```

so you can:

```py
Roles.to_dict() # {'ADMIN': 1, 'USER': 2, 'GUEST': 3}
Roles.keys() # ['ADMIN', 'USER', 'GUEST']
Roles.values() # [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 13):

Using a `classmethod` with `__members__`:

```
class RoleNames(str, Enum):
    AGENT = "agent"
    USER = "user"
    PRIMARY_USER = "primary_user"
    SUPER_USER = "super_user"
    
    @classmethod
    def list_roles(cls):
        role_names = [member.value for role, member in cls.__members__.items()]
        return role_names
```

```py
>>> role_names = RoleNames.list_roles()
>>> print(role_names)
```

or if you have multiple `Enum` classes and want to abstract the `classmethod`:

```
class BaseEnum(Enum):
    @classmethod
    def list_roles(cls):
        role_names = [member.value for role, member in cls.__members__.items()]
        return role_names


class RoleNames(str, BaseEnum):    
    AGENT = "agent"
    USER = "user"
    PRIMARY_USER = "primary_user"
    SUPER_USER = "super_user"
    

class PermissionNames(str, BaseEnum):
    READ = "updated_at"
    WRITE = "sort_by"
    READ_WRITE = "sort_order"
```

Answer (score 10):

So the `Enum` has a `__members__` dict. 
The solution that @ozgur proposed is really the best, but you can do this, which does the same thing, with more work

`[color.value for color_name, color in Color.__members__.items()]`

The `__members__` dictionary could come in handy if you wanted to insert stuff dynamically in it... in some crazy situation.

**[EDIT]**
Apparently `__members__` is not a dictionary, but a map proxy. Which means you can't easily add items to it.

You can however do weird stuff like `MyEnum.__dict__['_member_map_']['new_key'] = 'new_value'`, and then you can use the new key like `MyEnum.new_key`.... but this is just an implementation detail, and should not be played with. Black magic is payed for with huge maintenance costs.

Comment: Just a sidebar: can items be added to `__members__`? It would an interesting way to allow *extensions* thereby creating new `Enum` members. ... btw, upvoted for bringing a new (*to me*) attribute to the table.

Comment: @IAbstract: No, that is disallowed.  If someone does figure out a way to add/subtract members after the Enum is created they will probably break that Enum.

Comment: @IAbstract: Add new members after the fact is not usually a good idea.  If you really want to, check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35899963/208880).

Answer (score 10):

if you are using StrEnum or IntEnum, just use the built-in star expression to unpack:

```
from enum import IntEnum
class Color(IntEnum):
    RED = 0
    GREEN = 1
colors = [*Color]
```

Answer (score 8):

One way is to get the keys of the `_value2member_map_` property:

```
class Color(Enum):
    RED = 1
    BLUE = 2

list(Color._value2member_map_.keys())
# [1, 2]
```

Comment: Also there is `._member_map_` method too, it maybe useful in some cases.

Comment: This answer deserves to be higher up

Comment: Not sure why this isn't documented in the official docs for enum. This is super useful.

Answer (score 6):

Given an enum based on the standard python3 Enum/IntEnum classes:

```
from enum import IntEnum

class LogLevel(IntEnum):
    DEBUG = 0
    INFO = 1
    WARNING = 2
    ERROR = 3
```

one can do the following to get a list of enum constants:

```
>>> print(list(LogLevel))
[<LogLevel.DEBUG: 0>, <LogLevel.INFO: 1>, <LogLevel.WARNING: 2>, <LogLevel.ERROR: 3>]
```

I find it more expressive to work on enum constants instead of ints. If the enum is inheriting from IntEnum, all enum constants are also ints and can used as such everywhere:

```
>>> level = LogLevel.DEBUG

>>> level == 0
True

>>> level == 1
False

>>> level == LogLevel.INFO
False

>>> level == LogLevel.DEBUG
True

>>> "%d" % level
'0'

>>> "%s" % level
'LogLevel.DEBUG'
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are some examples to easily convert Enum to a list/array of int, str, or Enum AND be able to sort.

```
import numpy as np

class Color(int,Enum):
    YELLOW = 3
    RED = 1
    BLUE = 2
    
print('1):',list(Color))
print('2):',np.array(list(Color))) ## int64 (8 bytes)
print('3):',sorted(np.array(Color, dtype=str)))
print('4):',np.array(sorted(Color), dtype=object))
print('5):',np.array(sorted(Color), dtype=np.int8)) # 1 byte
print('6):',np.array(sorted(Color, key=lambda x: -x.value), dtype=np.int8))
print('7):',np.array(sorted(Color, key=lambda x: str(x)), dtype=np.int8))

class Color(tuple,Enum):
    YELLOW = (3,3)
    RED = (1,1)
    BLUE = (2,2)
    
print('8):',np.array(sorted(Color)))
print('9):',list(map(tuple,sorted(Color, key=lambda x: -x[1]))))
```

Output:

```
1): [<Color.YELLOW: 3>, <Color.RED: 1>, <Color.BLUE: 2>]
2): [3 1 2]
3): ['Color.BLUE', 'Color.RED', 'Color.YELLOW']
4): [<Color.RED: 1> <Color.BLUE: 2> <Color.YELLOW: 3>]
5): [1 2 3]
6): [3 2 1]
7): [2 1 3]
8): [[1 1]
 [2 2]
 [3 3]]
9): [(3, 3), (2, 2), (1, 1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative form of the `SuperEnum` suggested by @supermodo, which allows iterating over the key-value pairs, and has less magic:

```py
class SuperEnum(IntEnum):

    @classmethod
    def to_dict(cls):
        return {e.name: e.value for e in cls}

    @classmethod
    def items(cls):
        return [(e.name, e.value) for e in cls]

    @classmethod
    def keys(cls):
        return [e.name for e in cls]

    @classmethod
    def values(cls):
        return [e.value for e in cls]
```

Used like this:

```py
class Roles(SuperEnum):
    ADMIN = 1
    USER = 2
    GUEST = 3
```

Allows you to do:

```py
Roles.keys()  # ['ADMIN', 'USER', 'GUEST']
Roles.values()  # [1, 2, 3]
Roles.to_dict()  # {'ADMIN': 1, 'USER': 2, 'GUEST': 3}
for key, val in Roles.items():
    print(f"{key} > {val}")  # ADMIN -> 1, etc.
```

#### Generators (optimization)

Note that if you prefer generators over lists as return values for `items()`, `keys()` and `values()` then use round braces `()` instead of square brackets `[]`, e.g.

```py
    @classmethod
    def items(cls):
        return ((e.name, e.value) for e in cls)

    @classmethod
    def keys(cls):
        return (e.name for e in cls)

    @classmethod
    def values(cls):
        return (e.value for e in cls)
```

Generators are more memory-efficient and often preferred in the Python 3 standard library. The downside of them is that you need to convert them to lists to see the complete result (e.g. when working with them interactively), e.g.

```py
Roles.items()  # <generator object SuperEnum.items.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x7f3a8c787370>
list(Roles.items())  # [('ADMIN', 1), ('USER', 2), ('GUEST', 3)]
list(Roles.keys())  # ['ADMIN', 'USER', 'GUEST']
list(Roles.values())  # [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Im gonna throw another option into the mix.

If you don't want to refactor your current code with a different base class to all enums (like the inheritance answers in this thread), you can create a mixin class and just add it to the enums that need that functionality like so:

```
class ListValsMixIn:

    @classmethod
    def list(cls):
        return list(map(lambda c: c.value, cls))

class Color(ListValsMixIn, Enum):
    RED = 1
    BLUE = 2

print(Color.list())
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe an important comment on some of the answers above is to avoid naming a class method with the python builtin "list"

based on that: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/5884

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34544072)