# How to set all the enum values on a Pydantic field?

Tags: python, enums, fastapi, pydantic

I am using these classes as part of a FastAPI response:

```
class SomeRules(str, Enum):
    a_rule = "something"
    b_rule = "something_else"

class RuleChooser(BaseModel):
    rule: SomeRules = List[SomeRules]
```

In the JSON response, I want to get `rule` as:

```
{ 
    rule: ["something", "something_else"]
}
```

How do I achieve this?

Right now I am getting the output as:

```
rule: type.literal["something", "something_else"]
```

or

```
literal.type["A", "B", "C"]
```

I have tested multiple versions and none of them return the desired result.

- `rules = Literal["A", "B", "C"]`
- `rule: SomeRules = Somerules.rules`

Any help will be appreciated.

I am using Pydantic version 1.9.1

Comment: It's not clear what output you exactly need or how is this related to the type. Since you tagged this with [fastapi], I assume it's for a JSON response. If so, do you want to get something like `{rule: ["something", "something_else"]}`? Maybe it would help to show the "multiple versions" you tried.

Comment: Sorry, yes i am receiving JSON response. That is what i want. Now i am getting {rule: type.literal["something", "something_else"]}

Comment: I have tried with TypeVar("T") and GenericModel, also with a root_validator, and also it's mentioned in code comments.

Comment: You can edit your post by clicking on the **[Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72956666/edit)** link under the question. I've tried to clarify your post for you, by incorporating the previous comments, but you can improve it by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest, straightforward answer is to fix your definition for `rule`.

This

```
class RuleChooser(BaseModel):
    rule: SomeRules = List[SomeRules]
```

says that `rule` is of type `SomeRules` and its value is a [`typing.List`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/typing.html#typing.List) of `SomeRules`...which is definitely *wrong* because the value doesn't match the type. If you want `rule` to simply contain the string values of the enums, you can type it as `List[str]` then [get all the values of the enums](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29503339/2745495):

```
from pydantic import Field

class SomeRules(str, Enum):
    a_rule = "something"
    b_rule = "something_else"

class RuleChooser(BaseModel):
    rule: List[str] = Field(default=[rule.value for rule in SomeRules])

@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return RuleChooser()
```

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8000
{"rule":["something","something_else"]}
```

Now, I'm guessing you are using the actual enum members in your app (not their string values), and you just want `RuleChooser.rule` to be strings *only as part of the JSON response*. Then, you need to again fix the definition of `rule` to:

```
from pydantic import Field

class RuleChooser(BaseModel):
    rule: List[SomeRules] = Field(default=list(SomeRules))
```

which says that `rule` is of type [`typing.List`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/typing.html#typing.List) of `SomeRules`, and its value are [all the members of that Enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#iteration).

If you print an instance of `RuleChooser().rule`, you'll get:

```
[<SomeRules.a_rule: 'something'>, <SomeRules.b_rule: 'something_else'>]
```

But as part of the JSON response, FastAPI can handle the conversion from enum to string, and you'll get:

```
@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return RuleChooser()
```

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8000
{"rule":["something","something_else"]}
```

which is the same as what you wanted.