# Getting all values of an "enum" class of ctypes type

Tags: python, enums, ctypes

I'm struggling to find all values or iterate over all values for an enum class found in an SDK I need to make use of. The enums are not the classical `Enum` as python comes with but defined as

```
import ctypes
import ctypes.utils
XSULONG32 = ctypes.c_uint32
class XS_INFO(XSULONG32):
    XS_CONST0 = 0
    XS_CONST1 = 1
    XS_CONST2 = 2
```

I have code where I'd like to access both the constants values found in these classes, and ideally also the constants names left of the equal sign.

The intuitive approach of

```
for (name, value) in XS_INFO():
    print("{}: {}".format(name, value))
```

results in

```
TypeError: 'XS_INFO' object is not iterable
```

And similar trying other advice, e.g. the advice from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29503339/how-to-get-all-values-from-python-enum-class):

```
[hscam.XS_INFO().value for value in hscam.XS_INFO()]
TypeError: 'XS_INFO' object is not iterable

[hscam.XS_INFO.value for value in hscam.XS_INFO]
TypeError: '_ctypes.PyCSimpleType' object is not iterable
```

How can I iterate over all values of such enum?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that it is defined as a dict:

```
for name, value in XS_INFO.__dict__.items():
    if not name.startswith("__") and not callable(value):
        print(f"{name}: {value}")

XS_CONST0: 0
XS_CONST1: 1
XS_CONST2: 2
```

Thanks for being my rubber duck :)

Comment: Nice work to find your own answer! I was writing one using `dir(XS_INFO)` and the same `.startswith` logic, but the end result is the same.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up and thanks for your engagement, though. Much appreciated!