# Dynamically create an enum with custom values in Python?

Tags: python, enums

I would like to create an enum type at runtime by reading the values in a YAML file. So I have this:

```
# Fetch the values
v = {'foo':42, 'bar':24}

# Create the enum
e = type('Enum', (), v)
```

Is there a proper way to do it? I feel calling `type` is not a very neat solution.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why is your `Enum` having `e.foo` and `e.bar` attributes with such weird values assigned. It's not `Enum` at all!

Comment: @Nhor what is then? I am writing a wrapper from a C library where there is some enums like `typedef enum {soda = 3423, flower = 5827, water = 999} articles_t;` (this is an example obviously)

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You can create new enum type using [`Enum` functional API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#functional-api):

```
In [1]: import enum

In [2]: DynamicEnum = enum.Enum('DynamicEnum', {'foo':42, 'bar':24})

In [3]: type(DynamicEnum)
Out[3]: enum.EnumMeta

In [4]: DynamicEnum.foo
Out[4]: <DynamicEnum.foo: 42>

In [5]: DynamicEnum.bar
Out[5]: <DynamicEnum.bar: 24>

In [6]: list(DynamicEnum)
Out[6]: [<DynamicEnum.foo: 42>, <DynamicEnum.bar: 24>]
```

Comment: I wish we could do something like `class MyEnum(IntEnum): _list = ["A", "B", "C"]`

Comment: @PascalvKooten how about creating the dict like `{name: index for index, name in enumerate(the_list)}`.  It doesn't work for the dynamic (haven't looked into it) but for static it will autonumber.  https://repl.it/@altendky/SevereGiftedDuckbillcat

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28126314/adding-members-to-python-enums/35899963

Comment: Is there a way to inject also a type dynamically, for example `int` to produce `IntEnum`?