# Generate an enum class from a list in python

Tags: python-3.x

Suppose I want to create the following enum class:

```
from enum import Enum, unique

@unique
class Indication(Enum):
    Fruit1 = 'apple'
    Fruit2 = 'orange'
    Fruit3 = 'banana'
```

I want to create it from a python list, i.e.,

```
Listoffruits = [('Fruit1', 'apple'),  ('Fruit2', 'orange'), ('Fruit3',  'banana')]
```

How can this be done effectively?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically create an enum with custom values in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33690064/dynamically-create-an-enum-with-custom-values-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [Functional API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#functional-api) if you want to dynamically define an `Enum`:

```py
import enum

Listoffruits = [('Fruit1', 'apple'),  ('Fruit2', 'orange'), ('Fruit3',  'banana')]

Indication = enum.Enum('Indication', dict(Listoffruits))
```

You can use string formatting to "generate" the Python code:

```py
def generate_enum(enumClass, enumDict):
    """
    Generates python code for an Enum
    """

    enum_template = """
@unique
class {enumClass}(Enum)
{enumBody}
"""

    enumBody = '\n'.join([f"    {name} = '{value}'" for (name,value) in enumDict.items()])

    return enum_template.format(enumClass=enumClass,enumBody=enumBody)

print(generate_enum('Indication',dict(Listoffruits)))
```

The generated code will be:

```py
@unique
class Indication(Enum)
    Fruit1 = 'apple'
    Fruit2 = 'orange'
    Fruit3 = 'banana'
```

Comment: You don't need to convert a list of tuples to dict before passing to `enum.Enum`. Also your second solution just generates a string with enum class, but you'll need to evaluate it before using in your code. Is it any better than enum functional api approach?

Answer (score 2):

[Enum docs mentions a functional API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#functional-api). So you can just do:

```py
from enum import Enum
Indication = Enum('Indication', dict(Listoffruits))
```

Proof:

```py
>>> list(Indication)
[<Indication.Fruit1: 'apple'>,
 <Indication.Fruit2: 'orange'>,
 <Indication.Fruit3: 'banana'>]
```

As a matter of exploring Python, you can consider how this hack works (it does):

```py
from enum import Enum, unique

def inject_items(d, items):
    for k, v in items:
        d[k] = v

@unique
class Indication(Enum):
    inject_items(locals(), Listoffruits)
```

But that's just for educational purposes. I'd use `Enum`'s functional API for you purpose.