# is it possible in python to create an enum class from a (json) file?

Tags: python, json, enums

So i got a hardcoded class in my python project for enum use/purposes like this:

```
class Actions(Enum):
    go_to = 1
    open = 2
    close = 3
    ...
```

The class will not have any further functionality.

But I would like it to be more dynamic like the user to be able to define actions in a json file and then create the aforementioned Actions class from the json file (or any other file type).

Is this possible in python?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want it to be dynamic use a dictionary.

Comment: does it answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33690064/dynamically-create-an-enum-with-custom-values-in-python ? Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28126314/adding-members-to-python-enums/35899963 ?

Comment: @Grysik ha! I think this first post results in what i need. Though, I understand that this way, resonably enough, sicnce I create the enum on runtime it can not be interpreted by intelisense! The project compliles and seems to produces the expected results however!

Comment: Yeah, dynamic creation and intelisense is rather bad idea ;) . However intelisense should  work with it correctly during debugging.