# Using Enum to store constants and use those constants in multiple classes

Tags: java, enums, constants, cohesion

I'm currently writing a genetic algorithm solving the traveling salesman problem. There are some "constants" I use at multiple places. Those values, however, need to be precalculated, thus, I can't store them into a private static final variable.
Hence, I decided to use an Enum.

```
public enum Constants {
    NODE_COUNT(0),
    SEQUENCE_LENGTH(0),
    POPULATION_SIZE(0),
    MAX_EDGE_WEIGHT(0),
    MUTATION_RATE(0);

    private int value;
    private boolean alreadySet = false;

    Constants(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        if (!alreadySet) {
            this.value = value;
            this.alreadySet = true;
        } else {
            throw new AssertionError("Value is already set.");
        }
    }

    public int get() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

My question is, do you consider this a good approach? I'm not sure whether this lowers the cohesion of each class using the enum.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: These are not constants, they're state variables. It might make sense to collect these all into an `AlgorithmState` class, but they are not unique for all time.

Comment: See [Updating values of ENUM in java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47927733/17223316)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69890633/using-enum-to-store-constants-and-use-those-constants-in-multiple-classes#comment123545384_69890633), a constant that changes value is not a constant.

While you certainly *can* store changing state on an enum, you should ask yourself if doing so is a good idea. Generally not, in my opinion. Enum objects are usually used as constants, hence the convention of naming in all uppercase.

## `Map`

You can accomplish the goal of having type-safe limited set of objects (enums) along with more obviously changing state by using a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html). A map would pair each enum object with an object of a custom type to contain your changing state.

### `EnumMap`

The [`EnumMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumMap.html) class is an implementation of `Map` that is highly efficient, taking little memory and little CPU.

Here is some untested code as an example.

```java
enum TravSalesAspect NODE_COUNT, SEQUENCE_LENGTH, POPULATION_SIZE, MAX_EDGE_WEIGHT, MUTATION_RATE ;
record AlgorithmState ( int val , boolean alreadySet ) {} 

final Map< TravSalesAspect , AlgorithmState > map = new EnumMap<>() ;
```

Our map is empty. So we want to initialize with some default values.

We access an array of all the enum objects. From that array, we make a stream. For each element in the stream, we put a key-value entry into the map.

```java
Arrays.stream( TravSalesAspect.values() ).forEach( aspect -> map.put( aspect , new AlgorithmState( 0 , false ) ) ) ;  // Initializing the map.
```

When you want to later set the state:

```java
if( ! map.get( someAspect ).alreadySet() ) 
{
    map.put( someAspect , new AlgorithmState( 42 , true ) ) ; 
}
```

By the way, note that in Java 16+ both `enum` and `record` can be [defined locally](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) if you so desire.

Of course the code shown here is not thread-safe; beware.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bad approach to me. Enums are like classes, so there's no huge difference of making a dedicated class for those calculations. Then in fact why not creating typical class with those two fields only and instead of Enum, to keep their instances as `private static final` fields?

Comment: That is what I'm struggling with. For instance, NODE_COUNT: I use the graphStream library, so I can get node count of a graph by graph.getNodeCount(). (same for max edge weight). But I thought it might be better to precalculate those values (performance), as they never change. Using a private static final filed is not possible here.